# How to target multiple .net framework versions for a c# .net framework project (Not the sdk style)

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

How to target multiple .net framework versions for a c# .net framework project (Not the sdk style)

Need to target multiple .net versions to old .net framework project

Couldn't get the correct solution. All the results are showing about converting sdk style porject only.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line of code in your `.csproj` file and add your desired versions:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net472;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5;v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```